# SQL query select if list is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a question with sql query. In this case i need to get the users which last history activity was 14 days ago, but my history is empty, how i can do something like: if email history is empty on period 14 days, select without email history

```
SELECT st.id, st.firstName, st.lastName, st.email, st.lastLogin, st.phone,  st.gender, sa.title,bra.Title as brand, ss.SaleDate, teh.sDate, sa.imageUrl, sa.guid, st.mallId, sa.id saleId 
FROM dbo.Users st 
INNER JOIN KEY_SalesToUsers ss ON (st.ID=ss.userID) 
INNER JOIN Sales sa ON (sa.ID=ss.SaleID) 
INNER JOIN Brands bra ON (sa.BrandID=bra.ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo.UserEmailHistory teh ON st.id = teh.userId 
WHERE CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,1,ss.SaleDate))= CONVERT(date,getdate()) 
AND teh.sDate >= dateadd(dd,-14,getdate()) 
AND teh.sDate <=  dateadd(dd,-13,getdate()) 
AND sDate <=  dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) 
ORDER BY ss.SaleDate DESC
```

Comment: Read about `LEFT JOIN` vs. `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
INNER JOIN dbo.UserEmailHistory teh ON st.id = teh.userId
```

try to use

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserEmailHistory teh ON st.id = teh.userId
```

Comment: ok, but my history is empty right now. So the request will return empty array.  How i can exclude this point and return array if history is empty .

Answer (score 1):

You should read again LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN difference and also must change the where criteria. You dont need to check by <> two times. If the day is important for you convert date to day format and then check it. Performance will increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.id, st.firstName, st.lastName, st.email, st.lastLogin, st.phone,  st.gender, sa.title,bra.Title as brand, ss.SaleDate, teh.sDate, sa.imageUrl, sa.guid, st.mallId 
    FROM dbo.Users st 
    INNER JOIN KEY_SalesToUsers ss ON (st.ID=ss.userID) 
    INNER JOIN Sales sa ON (sa.ID=ss.SaleID) 
    INNER JOIN Brands bra ON (sa.BrandID=bra.ID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserEmailHistory teh ON st.id = teh.userId 
    WHERE CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,1,ss.SaleDate))=CONVERT(date,getdate()) 
    AND IsNull(sDate, '') = '' OR CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,14,teh.sDate))=CONVERT(date,getdate())  
    ORDER BY ss.SaleDate DESC
```